# Laravel 5.2.X validation error message not showing when using auth middleware

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I am working on a project where i have been assigned to develop a web application using using laravel. I am using laravel 5.2.x and each and everything working fine when route is not in auth group like login, logout etc.

After login i have define a group which can be access by only authenticated user like admin.

**routes.php**

```
/ Authentication Routes...
$this->get('/login', [ 'as' => 'auth.loginForm', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm']);
$this->get('/', [ 'as' => 'auth.loginRoot', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm']);
$this->post('/login',[ 'as' => 'auth.login', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@login']);
$this->get('/logout', [ 'as' => 'auth.logout', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@logout']);

// Password Reset Routes...
$this->get('/password/reset/{token?}', [ 'as' => 'auth.resetForm', 'uses' => 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm']);
$this->post('/password/email', [ 'as' => 'auth.passwdEmail', 'uses' => 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail']);
$this->post('/password/reset', [ 'as' => 'auth.reset', 'uses' => 'Auth\PasswordController@reset']);

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){

....

$this->get('/register', [ 'as' => 'auth.register', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm']);
    $this->post('/register', [ 'as' => 'auth.create', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@register']);
    $this->get('/register/verify/{confirmationCode}', ['as' => 'auth.confirmation', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@confirm']);
    $this->get('/dashboard', [ 'as' => 'auth.dashboard', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@index']);

....
});
```

Now, validation on register page working fine when i did `dd()` on controller, but the error message not showing up in blade. The validation i did in login and these are working fine. I don't understand what is the actual issue.

**updated:**
Session flash messages also not displaying, sometime display, but most of the time these error or session flash message not display.

**register.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.layout') @section('content')
<div class="panel-content register_cont">
    <div class="tabs_cont ">
        <ul class="tabs_btn nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="javascript:;" data-tab="tab1">New Account</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab1 active tab-pane">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="row">
                        {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'register', 'autocomplete' => 'off')) !!}
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                                <br/>
                                <h3><strong>New</strong> User Account</h3>
                                <hr/>
                                 <div class="form-group required {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    {{ Form::label('email', 'Email', array('class' => 'control-label')) }}
                                    {!! Form::text('email', old('email'), array('placeholder' => 'Email Address', 'class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                                    @if ($errors->has('email')) 
                                        <div class="error-msg">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</div>
                                    @else
                                        <div class="error-msg">Email is required</div> 
                                    @endif
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 required {{ $errors->has('title') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        {!! HTML::decode(Form::label('title', 'Title <span class="red-astrisk">*</span>', array('class' => 'control-label'))) !!}
                                        {{ Form::select('title', ['' => 'Title', 'Mr.' => 'Mr.', 'Mrs.' => 'Mrs.', 'Miss.' => 'Miss.', 'Dr.' => 'Dr.'], old('title'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                                        @if ($errors->has('title')) 
                                            <div class="error-msg">{{ $errors->first('title') }}</div>
                                        @else
                                            <div class="error-msg">Title is required</div> 
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8 required {{ $errors->has('first_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        {!! HTML::decode(Form::label('first_name', 'First Name <span class="red-astrisk">*</span>', array('class' => 'control-label'))) !!}
                                        {!! Form::text('first_name', old('first_name'), array('placeholder' => 'First Name', 'class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                                        @if ($errors->has('first_name')) 
                                            <div class="error-msg">{{ $errors->first('first_name') }}</div>
                                        @else
                                            <div class="error-msg">First name is required</div> 
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group required {{ $errors->has('last_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    {!! HTML::decode(Form::label('last_name', 'Last Name <span class="red-astrisk">*</span>', array('class' => 'control-label'))) !!}
                                    {!! Form::text('last_name', old('last_name'), array('placeholder' => 'Last Name', 'class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                                    @if ($errors->has('last_name')) 
                                        <div class="error-msg">{{ $errors->first('last_name') }}</div>
                                    @else
                                        <div class="error-msg">Last name is required</div> 
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                <hr/>
                                <div class="form-group btn_cont">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme">Create</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Please help me.

Comment: Where do you print your $errors ? Why didn't you use the default auth behaviour ( routing ) - did you also create your own auth views?

Comment: i have print errors in controller using dd(); and it is shoring the rules failed and the message corresponding to these failed rules. I am printing error in register page which is develop using blade. I am also updating register.blade.php above. Please check.

Comment: where in the controller did you dd the errors? Did you use the default controller ? or did you write your own? how do you redirect users back? Ensure the session is the same where you dd in controller and when you are in your blade view. Maybe the session changed after login failed

Comment: I have create make auth laravel default controller, then i customized that controller i am writing my own validation and saving in my controller. If you want i can post it too. This issue is not related to register only, this is happening with other blade too.

Comment: it the web middleware also applied correctly? otherwise you will not have a correct session handling

Comment: I have not added web default myself as it is already added by laravel. I am using auth middleware in group routing, as you can see above in my posted question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118514/discussion-between-mandy-and-frank-provost).